# Retag [photosframework] as [photokit]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Both tags[photosframework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/photosframework) and [photokit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/photokit) are referring to the new iOS 8 photos framework, more readily known as PhotoKit. Cf. https://developer.apple.com/ios8/, search for PhotoKit.